# Django: error en configuracion de url's

Tags: python, django, linux

Estoy Usando

- django en su version: 1.11.4
- python 3.6 en linux debian

Tengo configurado los siguientes archivos en
**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'about',
    'contact',
   ]
```

**urls.py** esta configurado asi:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from home import views
from about import views
from contact import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.About, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.Contact, name='contact'),
]
```

**home/views.py**  con el siguiente codigo

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Home.html')
```

**contacto/views.py** lo escribi asi

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Contact


def contact(request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Contact.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

por ultimo tengo la carpeta ***templates*** con sus archivos:

- home.html,
- about.html,
- contact.html

Al ejecutar el comando

```
python manage runserver
```

la consola muestra el siguiente error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

    url(r'^home/$', views.Home, name='home'),
    AttributeError: module 'contact.views' has no attribute 'Home'
```

He realizado diferentes configuraciones,no encuentro cual es el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿No es un tema de mayúsculas?
Tienes en home view redirección a Home.html (¿no sería home.html?).
Luego en urls.py dices view.Home y tu función es home.
También, no sé si es correcto que importes las tres vistas con el mismo nombre views. En el curso que seguí yo de django hacía import views as viewhome y en el urls.py haces viewhome.miFuncion.

Answer (score 2):

Veo algunos problemas.

1. Tus vistas las has definido con minúsculas, no con mayúsculas
2. Estás importando todos los `views` con el mismo nombre:

   ```
   from home import views
   from about import views
   from contact import views
   ```

   Si lo haces de esa forma entonces el último `views` es el que prevalece (el de tu aplicación `contact`). Intenta hacerlo con nombres específicos:

   ```
   from home import views as home_views
   from about import views as about_views
   from contact import views as contact_views

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
       url(r'^home/$', home_views.home, name='home'),
       url(r'^about/$', about_views.about, name='about'),
       url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
   ]
   ```

Teniendo esto claro, el código completo de tus URLs debería ser:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from home import views as home_views
from about import views as about_views
from contact import views as contact_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$', home_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', about_views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Comment: Gracias,estuve probando y lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

**from django.conf.urls import url, include**

**from contact import views**

 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^about/$', include('about.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
 ]



Tambien corrregi las mayusculas, por otro lado use su explicacion y funciona perfecto, Me surge una pregunta de que depende usar las url's con **include** o **class based views**

Comment: @Developer claro, esa es otra opción. lo ideal es que uses `include()` y tengas un archivo `urls.py` para cada app. Si tienes dudas con Class Based Views crea otra pregunta y te ayudo.